# Running Next.js App on EC2 Instance with IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, amazon-ec2, next.js

I have an AWS EC2 instance for my Next.js website. If I open the terminal on my Next.js app and run `next start` it runs fine and I can visit the website. However, I then need to always keep the terminal open on the instance for the website to work.

My question is, can I use IIS to keep a Next.js website running with `next start`? I don't want to create a full node backend to serve static html pages because it will mess up some of the dynamic aspects of the website. So is there a way to run a Next.js app by itself without running `next export` for the static pages?

**UPDATE**

I attempted to run the Next.js app with PM2 instead. When I run `npm start` in the terminal it works fine. However, when I run `pm2 start npm -- start` (or any variation of that), it stops the server and logs this error multiple times:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forever to run your process in the backend, the below example is how to implement it with iis

https://www.technoapple.com/blog/post/run-node-as-background-by-using-forever

Comment: I tried using forever but, after running ```forever npm run start``` I received the error ```script C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\client\npm does not exist```. I then pointed forever to the next directory with ```forever ./node_modules/.bin/next start``` and I received the following error: ```basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list```

Comment: the command should be like forever start -c "npm run start" ./

Comment: that command is not working either. It just says ```Forever processing file``` and then nothing happens